# SignalR or Web API to update business entites

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, signalr

Let's say I have a web application that is an auction site. It employs ASP.NET Web API to query the server for business data but SignalR is also used for certain real-time aspects of the site. For example, if User A makes an auction and User B puts a bid on it, User A gets notified in real time that someone has put a bid on his auction. If User C also puts a bid on the same item, User B also gets notified that he has been outbid.

Given this scenario, I'm wondering whether it'd be "correct use of the toolset" to simply use a SignalR hub to call into the service layer to update the appropriate objects in the database as well as pushing the notifications to the appropriate clients. Or, should I use a Web API controller to do the service layer call which performs any db manipulation and get a hub instance through OWIN Context and only use SignalR for broadcasting?

What are the advantages/disadvantages of each approach? I guess the second option is the correct way, but I don't have anything in my mind to support it... it just feels more correct.

I'd also point out that Web API isn't used for no reason - I think that an auction application is such a thing for which dedicated mobile/tablet applications would perfectly make sense to be made and having a way to get data independently from view markup is pretty much what Web API is made for. The same applies to sending data to the server - representing actions as HTTP verbs and urls is something that I like to think of as a sort of a convention, so I guess using SignalR for such actions would kind of break the whole point of using Web API.

Comment: With both roads doing well the transmission, I'd take the WebApi way as it is easier to debug, trace. And it looks easier to implement on the client side. Btw this whole thing sounds like a good way to be implemented via some business layer events bus.

Comment: I had to make the same decision and decided to use the Web API. Main reason for me was the fact that I could use my already existing authentication attributes on the server side.

Comment: I've used both before in a similar situation, WebAPI for most of the work and SignalR when you need the real time aspect. WebAPI is generally easier to work with, and you can get a ton of functionality with EnableQuery very quickly so you don't have to keep writing new methods for slightly different calls (just remember to lock it down when done)

Comment: Like you have already mentioned, there is a reason for you to use WebAPI - primarily to be able to write mobile/tablet application.
One thing that SignalR has a restriction on is - no support for headers. So to then pass authentication token you will have to use some other mechanism, like querystring, and that does not sound good.